# C++ error: Free() invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++

I just have a 10 line c++ program and it throws a half page error when I run it.

This is the following program

```
void getDataset(double ** f, int nRows, int nAttribute){
    ifstream u;
    u.open("iris.txt");


    for(int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < nAttribute; j++)
            u >> f[i][j];
}

int main(){
    int nRows = 150, nAttribute = 4, k = 3;

    double * mat[nRows];
    for(int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
        mat[i] = new double(nAttribute);
    }
    mat[149][3] = 2;
    getDataset(mat, nRows, nAttribute);
    cout << mat[100][2] << endl;
}
```

I tried to copy the error using ./a.out > error.log but its not working. The error.log is empty. So I had to copy paste it here, directly.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000ef1520 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e846)[0x7f8ba675b846]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x23)[0x7f8ba704cc13]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNKSt7num_getIcSt19istreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE6do_getES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseRSt12_Ios_IostateRd+0xf5)[0x7f8ba703cb25]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSi10_M_extractIdEERSiRT_+0x8f)[0x7f8ba702d22f]
./a.out[0x40170c]
./a.out[0x40186f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f8ba66fe76d]
./a.out[0x400aa9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 524669                             /home/aditya/Documents/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:06 524669                             /home/aditya/Documents/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 524669                             /home/aditya/Documents/a.out
00eee000-00f0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f8ba66dd000-7f8ba6892000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1447163                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f8ba6892000-7f8ba6a91000 ---p 001b5000 08:06 1447163                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f8ba6a91000-7f8ba6a95000 r--p 001b4000 08:06 1447163                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f8ba6a95000-7f8ba6a97000 rw-p 001b8000 08:06 1447163                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f8ba6a97000-7f8ba6a9c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ba6a9c000-7f8ba6ab1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1440108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8ba6ab1000-7f8ba6cb0000 ---p 00015000 08:06 1440108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8ba6cb0000-7f8ba6cb1000 r--p 00014000 08:06 1440108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8ba6cb1000-7f8ba6cb2000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 1440108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8ba6cb2000-7f8ba6dad000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1447283                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f8ba6dad000-7f8ba6fac000 ---p 000fb000 08:06 1447283                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f8ba6fac000-7f8ba6fad000 r--p 000fa000 08:06 1447283                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f8ba6fad000-7f8ba6fae000 rw-p 000fb000 08:06 1447283                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f8ba6fae000-7f8ba7090000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 400528                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f8ba7090000-7f8ba728f000 ---p 000e2000 08:06 400528                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f8ba728f000-7f8ba7297000 r--p 000e1000 08:06 400528                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f8ba7297000-7f8ba7299000 rw-p 000e9000 08:06 400528                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f8ba7299000-7f8ba72ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ba72ae000-7f8ba72d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1447286                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f8ba74b3000-7f8ba74b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ba74cd000-7f8ba74d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8ba74d0000-7f8ba74d1000 r--p 00022000 08:06 1447286                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f8ba74d1000-7f8ba74d3000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 1447286                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff6ef55000-7fff6ef76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff6ef8c000-7fff6ef8d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Comment: Did you mean `mat[i] = new double[nAttribute];`?

Comment: Regarding capturing the error log.  You need to set LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_ variable to something non-empty.  Otherwise glibc will dump the log to /dev/tty directly.  I mean something like LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1 ./program 2> error.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating a double array with `new double(nAttribute)`.  Your code needs to change to `new double[ nAttribute ]`.

Comment: Why is the error so sporadically thrown? I was working with the same fragment for the past half an hour or so and it worked fine :|

Comment: It just depends on what memory address you get at runtime when you dereference and/or assign to `f[i][j]`.  The address in all cases is "undefined", so sometimes it will resolve to an address your program can write to, which is still going to cause corruption but won't necessarily crash immediately, and sometimes it'll be a location you have no read or write access to.  In that case it'll crash immediately.